# Global helper for Zend module-structure

Tags: helper, view-helpers, zend-framework

My files look like this:

```
/Zend
  /Application
    /Configs
    /Modules
       /home
          /controllers
          /views
       /login
          /controllerS              
          /forms
          /library
             /login
          /models
          /plugins
          /views
```

I would like to create a helper which which can be used by all modules. Kinda a "global helper". Is there a standard way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of helper? View? Or something like a action helper? If it's just a utility style class (not attached to a specific part of the MVC), just putting it in `/library/NAMESPACE` works well.

Then just add that namespace to the autoloader in `application.ini`.

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = NAMESPACE
```

And you can then

```
$helper = new NAMESPACE_Helper();
```

Comment: `  $view = new Zend_View();
  $mypath=$this->view->getHelperPaths();
  $view->addHelperPath($mypath['Login_View_Helper_'], 'RenderIfExists');
        $this->renderIfExists('login.phtml'); `

Comment: `  $view = new Zend_View();
  $mypath=$this->view->getHelperPaths();
  $view->addHelperPath($mypath['Login_View_Helper_'][0], 'RenderIfExists');
        $this->renderIfExists('login.phtml'); ` This gives me the error: `Message: Method "renderIfExists" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()`. My path to my helper is correct. I've checked it with `echo $mypath['Login_View_Helper_'][0]`